# Find a view which was tapped (clicked) in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a "cell" in my list with picture, text and a checkbox. Here's my xml
`fragment_people_list_item.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    // ... more elements
    <CheckBox />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'd like to distinguish if user taps on a checkbox or on the rest of the view. A relevant part of my `RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener`:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

}
```

It says that `findChildViewUnder` finds the topmost view under the given point which is ALWAYS my `RelativeLayout`!

How can I know on which view exactly user tapped (clicked)?

Comment: You should use custom adapter to acomplish such thing.
Try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13220810/783612.

Comment: Well I I can easily attach an `OnClickListener` or `OnCheckedChangeListener`. The problem is that clicking on a checkbox do 2 things: 1. ticks a checkbox itself; 2: is propogated further to my `onInterceptTouchEvent` listener

Comment: And in my `onInterceptTouchEvent` listener I don't want to call `setChecked` on my checkbox if the click was on it and vise versa. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

To distinguish clicks on checkBox from clicks on the rest of the list item you should use custom adapter for your list and override getView. In getView method you can set OnClickListener separately for your checkBox and for the item.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("@@@", "checkbox clicked");
        }
    });
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("@@@", "item clicked");
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: I certainly use my own adapter which extends from `RecyclerView.Adapter` and it doesn't have a method `getView` to override.

Comment: Sorry, `getView` method is used in adapter for `ListView`. In adapter for `RecyclerView` the same thing may be applied in `onBindViewHolder` method.